# Как реализовать приход сообщения в реальном времени для WAP браузера китайского кнопочного телефона?

Tags: php, long-polling, wap

Я имею аппарат MAXVI С20 (кнопочный китайский телефон), в нем есть WAP браузер (который совершенно не знает что такое Java Script и Css).

Как я понимаю данный браузер понимает только HTML разметку (и то вроде не всю). Хотя возможно надо использовать WML (но я если честно даже не знаю чем WML отличается от HTML).
Но это не главное. А главное вот что:

Как реализовать приход информации от сервера в реальном времени?

Например пользователь в чате отправляет сообщение. Но я могу его увидеть, только если обновлю страницу.

Как получить новое сообщение не обновляя страницу?

Гугл меня привел к Long Polling на php, однако это работает плохо. Так как браузер после 30 секундного ожидания, говорит "Извини братан, так долго ответ сервера я ждать не собираюсь" и прекращает "ждать". В итоге нужно снова обновлять страницу.

В общем подскажите как можно реализовать вариант с получением новой информации от сервера без обновления страницы? Раньше ведь вроде как-то работали чаты на кнопочниках?

Заранее большое спасибо за любые идеи.

Comment: Отправляйте ответ чуть раньше, например через 28 секунд?

Comment: Ну например собеседник еще не написал ничего (например он ответит через 1 минуту только).
Проходит 28 секунд. Если за это время собеседник не написал ничего, то сервер посылает false клиенту (то есть мне на вап браузер), у меня страница отображается без изменений, соединение завершено. (Так как у меня нет JS и я не могу сгенерировать новый (например ajax) запрос из браузера).
Что делать?

Comment: а с помощью чего вы отправляете запрос это первый, что приходит через 28 секунд? зы: если у вас  нет js, то кроме как meta refresh хз что вообще сделать можно, если хоть это браузер позволяет ваш

Comment: Ну получается у меня обычная форма и кнопка на html-ле. Пишу сообщение, нажимаю <button> "Отправить", форма посылает на файл php post запрос с содержанием введенного в input сообщения. Далее на сервере реализуется цикл, который выполняется до тех пор пока собеседник не ответит, или пока не пройдет 28 секунд). Если собеседник ответил, то все хорошо. Посылаем новую html страницу с новым сообщением клиенту (то есть мне на wap браузер).

Comment: Но если человек за 28 секунд не ответил, посылаем страницу без изменений. Соединение закрывается. Дальше если собеседник ответит, то мы не увидим его сообщение, пока не обновим страницу. Я узнал что мой браузер поддерживает WMLScript (но походу он не имеет средств для решения моей проблемы). В общем нужно получать новое сообщение когда оно придет от собеседника даже если прошло 30 секунд. Буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Comment: Спасибо teran, <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://сайт.ru/?гет параметры"> Действительно более-менее решает мою проблему. Конечно не так, как хотелось бы, но все-же это заработало! Большое спасибо!